# Why doesn't '[0-9]*' match 'abc' in my Python regular expression since there are zero or more digits in the string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, grep, character-class

Why does this regex:

```
>>> r = re.compile("[0-9]*", re.DEBUG)
```

match like this:

```
>>> m = r.search("abc")
>>> m.group()
''
```

I was hoping that it would match the entire string `'abc'` since `'a'` fulfills the condition viz match 0 digits, and then the greedy match would include the string `'abc'` in its entirety.

Comment: [0-9]* matches digits, why do you expect "abc" will match it?

Comment: @XiaotianPei Because "abc" contains 0 digits. See my point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked "find me zero or more digits", so it found you zero or more digits (zero; empty string).

If you wanted "find me zero or more digits followed by zero or more other characters", you need to *say* that (with the `.*` pattern). `'[0-9]*'` does not *match* `'abc'`, because `'abc'` includes characters (letters) not included in the requested expression.

```
>>> r = re.compile('[0-9]*.*')  # Note the very important ".*" that matches everything!
>>> r.search('abc').group()
'abc'
```

---

The point is the word "match". If your expression does not contain [a representation of] a certain character (such as "a"), then it cannot possibly *match* a string that contains that character! Your given expression matches only strings *consisting of zero or more digits and nothing else*. Therefore it clearly doesn't match `'abc'`.

---

As Tigerhawk has mentioned in the comments, if the `*` in regular expressions meant "zero or more of the preceding pattern, *or anything else*", it would be extraordinarily useless, as any pattern with a `*` in it would match all strings, all the time!

Comment: Sorry may be I am coming across as too pedantic but "abc" completely satisfies the condition stated in the regex, which is: find me 0 or more digits.

Comment: @abc It found you zero or more digits. You didn't ask to match non-digit characters, and therefore such characters were not matched.

Comment: Again, if `*` worked like that, it would match everything to the end of a string and thus be quite useless.

Comment: @abc No, it satisfies what you *think* you asked it, but you don't get to redefine the language to fit your mental map. What you actually asked Python to do was to "return a matching pattern of zero or more of the characters in the preceding class, which *does **not** include* any alphabetical characters." Since it *did* match zero digits, it correctly returned the matched pattern, which happens to be the empty string.

Comment: @CodeGnome Good points. Thanks a lot. I upvoted your answer below as well. Henry's answer seems to answer my question the most.

Answer (score 5):

You searched for 0 or more digits. It found 0 or more digits. The exact number of digits that it found was 0. Hence, the empty string.

Answer (score 4):

### Use a Negated Character Class

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314155/explain-this-regex-match#comment54427096_33314155) above, you say you expect `[0-9]*` to match `abc` because:

> "abc" contains 0 digits.

You're misunderstanding what a character class is, and that it contains atoms. Yours is not currently a negative assertion.

You *could* get a match with `[^0-9]*` if you don't precompile it. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("[^0-9]*", "abc").group()
'abc'
```

This would perhaps fit your mental map, but thinking of negated character classes as "not containing a range" as opposed to "not containing any of the *included* characters" is probably going to lead you astray in the future. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

becouse your regex looking only for digits and abc doesn't have any digits in it.

in short your regex matches anything with digits and the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.regex.findall), `search()` does the following:

> Scan through string looking for a location where this regular
>   expression produces a match, and return a corresponding match object.
>   Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note
>   that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point
>   in the string.

Thus, the fact that `m` is not `None` indicates that it found a match. The fact that `m.group()` returns `''` shows *what it matched*.

Comment: But why did it match empty string and not "abc" which contains zero numbers.

Comment: If `*` worked like that, it would always consume until the end of the string. Instead, it only consumes the character it's supposed to repeat.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 "* only consumes the character it's supposed to repeat", good point.